# reduce grouped data frame by intersecting values in each group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Is there a way in pure dplyr or data.table to group by one column and then reduce each group so that they end up only containing the rows where the values of another column intersect?

Here is an example:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
classification <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10)
set.seed(123)
id.list <- lapply(1:3, function(i) sample(letters[1:7], 10, replace = T))
dtbl <- tibble(classification = classification, id = unlist(id.list), value = round(runif(30, 50, 99)))
```

This produces the following:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   classification id    value
   <chr>          <chr> <dbl>
 1 A              g        84
 2 A              g        89
 3 A              c        51
 4 A              f        73
 5 A              c        87
 6 A              b        61
 7 A              b        66
 8 A              f        61
 9 A              c        57
10 A              e        70
11 B              d        70
12 B              f        68
13 B              f        57
14 B              a        57
15 B              b        61
16 B              c        73
17 B              e        63
18 B              c        92
19 B              c        52
20 B              a        72
21 C              d        89
22 C              a        56
23 C              a        77
24 C              e        60
25 C              c        56
26 C              b        87
27 C              g        94
28 C              b        68
29 C              a        83
30 C              f        55
```

The values of id that appear in each classification group are `b`, `c`, `e` and `f`. I can get the desired result by doing:

```
common.id <- Reduce(intersect, id.list)
dtbl.intersect <- filter(dtbl, id %in% common.id) %>% 
  arrange(classification, id, value)
```

Which gives me:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   classification id    value
   <chr>          <chr> <dbl>
 1 A              b        61
 2 A              b        66
 3 A              c        51
 4 A              c        57
 5 A              c        87
 6 A              e        70
 7 A              f        61
 8 A              f        73
 9 B              b        61
10 B              c        52
11 B              c        73
12 B              c        92
13 B              e        63
14 B              f        57
15 B              f        68
16 C              b        68
17 C              b        87
18 C              c        56
19 C              e        60
20 C              f        55
```

But I don't like having to break out of a dplyr pipeline in order to create `common.id`. Is it possible to perform the entire process in dplyr or data.table?

**EDIT**
As correctly pointed out in the responses: I'm looking for a solution that does not use the `id.list` list (that's just part of the MWE). A broader question is: does the dplyr/data.table grouping operation create a list "somewhere" that can be used by a reduce function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (with the addition of `purrr`):

```
dtbl %>%
 filter(id %in% reduce(id.list, intersect)) %>%
 arrange(classification, id, value)
```

Or:

```
dtbl %>%
 filter(id %in% Reduce(intersect, id.list)) %>%
 arrange(classification, id, value)
```

Or if the question is more focused on creating id.list:

```
dtbl %>%
 mutate(n = n_distinct(classification)) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(classification) == n) %>%
 select(-n) %>%
 arrange(classification, id, value)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `data.table` package as follows:

```
  setDT(dtbl)
  dtbl[, .SD[id %in% Reduce(intersect, id.list)], by = classification
       ][order(classification, id)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 comparable (in terms of speed) methods using `data.table`:

```
mtd0 <- function(DT) {
    IDs <- DT[, unique(id)]
    invisible(DT[, IDs <<- intersect(IDs, id), classification])
    DT[id %in% IDs][order(classification, id, value)]
}

mtd1 <- function(DT) {
    DT[DT[, .(id=Reduce(intersect, split(id, classification)))], on=.(id), nomatch=0L][
        order(classification, id, value)]
}
```

I think your `id.list` has confused us, making us think that it was available as a standalone variable although you merely used it to create a MWE.

data:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.4
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e7
nclass <- 1e4
nid <- 1e2
dat <- data.table(classification=sample(nclass, nr, TRUE),
    id=sample(nid, nr, TRUE))[, value := .I]
setorder(dat, classification, id, value)
```

timings from `bench::mark(mtd0(dat), mtd1(dat))`:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                   memory                time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                   <list>                <list>   <list>          
1 mtd0(DT)   810.17ms 810.17ms     1.23      897MB     3.70     1     3   810.17ms <df[,3] [6,197,991 x 3]> <df[,3] [80,334 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd1(DT)      1.33s    1.33s     0.752     854MB     3.01     1     4      1.33s <df[,3] [6,197,991 x 3]> <df[,3] [94,322 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Comment: very much agree @chinsoon12, I shouldn't have including `id.list` in the NWE. Thinking about it, the broader question, of which this is a specific example, is: it *seems* as though dplyr/data.table groupings are in some way a list structure therefore it should be possible to apply a reduce operation over a column in these groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
setDT(dtbl)
result <- dtbl[id %chin% Reduce(intersect, id.list)] # %chin% is fast %in% for characters
setorder(result, classification, id, value)
```

Comment: %chin% is good to know. Is there any way to not use `id.list` i.e., use only `dtbl` to get to the result?

Comment: ...also I think you would need an intersect step somewhere here too.

Comment: @Dave_L Oh sorry, I didn't read properly. Inserted intersect again. Well you are selecting the rows based on `id.list` I don't know how you want to be able to omit it.